# Using foreign keys that reference primary keys as primary keys for other tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am creating a MySQL db that tracks multiple versions of client's financial info. To do so I am creating a client table:

```
CREATE TABLE client
(
    clientID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fName VARCHAR(255),
    lName VARCHAR(255),
    dateCreated DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY clientID
)
ENGINE=INNODB;
```

and I have to track multiple financial sheets for each client:

```
CREATE TABLE finSheet
(
    sheetID INT NOT NULL,
    clietID INT NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    dateMade date,
    PRIMARY KEY sheetID,
    FOREIGN KEY clientID REFERENCES client(clientID)
)
ENGINE=INNODB;
```

And then lastly I have to create multiple tables for all the financial info we take on each "sheet"

```
CREATE TABLE financials
(
    -- does client name come as a foreign key??? --
   estateAddress VARCHAR(255),
   yearPurchase INT(4),
   balanceOwed INT,
   homeValue INT,
   asset1Notes TEXT,
)
ENGINE=INNODB;
```

How do I properly create my financials table so that finsheet's unique identifier is the unique identifier for financials. But also, how can I pull first and last name from the original client record that the finsheet is under?

Comment: Does a finsheet has only one financials entry ? Is it one-to-one ? Or one-to-many ?

Comment: finsheet has one to one financials entry. but client is one to many on finsheets

Comment: Use sheetID as PK in financials table. It should also be FK to sheetID in sheet table. To get client name, join from financials to sheet to client